# Two divs not aligning

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am not able to align my div named `#time` horizontally with another div named `.content`.

Click here for a live version of the website - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/73176512/InteractiveGuide/index.html

The time div is not aligning with the content div. Code can be viewed by right clicking and viewing source. Or I can paste it here if requested.

I am floating the #time div right.

Comment: @DreamEater it is just a draft rough version, I will change it of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code with this,

```
.upper {
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 1048px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.content {
    background-color: #FFF9EC;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px gray;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0;
    min-width: 1024px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Please remove padding Left and Right form .content

Thanks
Safder Jaffri

Answer (score 0):

Give the `#time` div a margin-right of -22px (I just eyeballed this so check for sure)

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution enjoy just give your upper class min-width to 1070px

```
    .upper
 {
float:left;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
min-width: 1070px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative right margin to #time, this way:

```
#time {
    margin-right: -40px;
}
```